# Extract lines from a huge text file through two identifier as start and end using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I  wrote a function to extract a particular block of text from a large text file, the example text is presented below:

```
 ATP(1):C39(3) - A:TYR(58):CD2(67)
     ATP(1):C39(3) - A:TYR(58):CE2(69)
     ATP(1):C59(6) - A:ILE(61):CD1(100)
     ATP(1):C59(6) - A:LYS(87):CE(344)

Hydrogen bonds:
    Location of Donor | Sidechain/Backbone | Secondary Structure | Count 
   -------------------|--------------------|---------------------|-------
          LIGAND      |      SIDECHAIN     |        OTHER        |   1   

         RECEPTOR     |      BACKBONE      |         BETA        |   1   

Raw data:
     ATP(1):O2A(9) - A:ILE(61):HN(93) - A:ILE(61):N(92)

Hydrophobic contacts (C-C):
    Sidechain/Backbone | Secondary Structure | Count 
   --------------------|---------------------|-------
         SIDECHAIN     |        OTHER        |   2   
         SIDECHAIN     |         BETA        |   23  

Raw data:
     ATP(1):C39(3) - A:TYR(58):CD2(67)
     ATP(1):C39(3) - A:TYR(58):CE2(69)
     ATP(1):C59(6) - A:ILE(61):CD1(100)
     ATP(1):C59(6) - A:LYS(87):CE(344)
     ATP(1):C4(23) - A:PHE(209):CD1(1562)
     ATP(1):C4(23) - A:PHE(209):CE1(1564)
     ATP(1):C2(26) - A:PHE(209):CD2(1563)
     ATP(1):C6(28) - A:PHE(209):CB(1560)
     ATP(1):C6(28) - A:PHE(209):CG(1561)
     ATP(1):C6(28) - A:PHE(209):CD1(1562)
     ATP(1):C6(28) - A:VAL(286):CG2(2266)

pi-pi stacking interactions:
     ATP(1):C8(30) - A:LYS(87):CG(342)
     ATP(1):C8(30) - A:GLU(159):CD(1066)
     ATP(1):C8(30) - A:PHE(209):CE1(1564)
```

I wrote a function to extract the chunk:

```
from itertools import islice

def start_end_points(file_name):


    f = open(file_name)
    lines = f.readlines()

    for s, line in enumerate(lines):
        if "Hydrogen bonds:" in line:
            print s

    for e, line in enumerate(lines):
        if "pi-pi stacking interactions:" in line:
            print e

    print islice(lines, s, e) 

start_end_points("foo.txt")
```

Is there a way to write this code more efficiently? Because I want to use this code as part of a Web tool, hence efficiency of the code is very important.

Thanks.

Comment: What do want to do exactly? Extract everything between a line containing *Hydrogen bonds* up to a line containing *pi-pi stacking interactions:*? May these blocks happen more than once in the file and to you want to keep all if it happens? Without more informations, all I can say is that `readlines` on a huge file is not memory efficient...

Comment: may be you can use linecache! https://pymotw.com/2/linecache/

Comment: @SergeBallesta Bothe the  identifiers are Uniques and happen to have once in a file.

Comment: There is an error in your code btw. `s` and `e` will equal the length of the file after executing both `for` loops. You may want `break` statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no reason to load the whole file to memory!

```
def start_end_points(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        found = False
        for line in f:
            if found or ("Hydrogen bonds:" in line):
                found = True
                print line
            if "pi-pi stacking interactions:" in line:
                break

start_end_points("foo.txt")
```

That way you keep only one buffer in memory, process each line once, and stop reading the file as soon as you have reached the *pi-pi...* line.

Comment: @elena: thank you for the edit. I erroneously changed it again but I've now reverted to your version

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to save all lines to memory!

The `with` efficient closes the file automatically, so it's very efficient and useful.

**Pay attention** to the 2 options - if it's all about efficientcy, choose the first.

**I recommend** `return`ing the lines and not `print`ing it - maybe you'll have extra use in it, and then you can just print in again, and not run the whole function again.

```
def start_end_points(file_name):

    wanted_text = ""

    # USE this way -EFFICIENT!

    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        found = False
        for line in f:
            if found:
                if "pi-pi stacking interactions:" in line:
                    break
                else:
                    wanted_text += line 
            if "Hydrogen bonds:" in line:
                wanted_text += line
                found = True



    # OR use this way *less efficient memory speaking*, but pythonic

    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        all = f.read().split('\n')
        numbers = [i for i, line in enumerate(all) if "Hydrogen bonds:" in line or "pi-pi stacking interactions:" in line]
        wanted_text = all[numbers[0]:numbers[1]]


    # eventually, return:
    return wanted_text


data = start_end_points("foo.txt")
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put `if found` condition first and the `elif` for the second condition. I think that would avoid some checks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more efficient because you can iterate over `f` so you save yourself this list transformation `lines = f.readlines()`. Also this code executes only runs one time trough the data (using 2 while loops) where your code used 2 for loops both running to the end of the file.

```
from pprint import pprint


def start_end_points(file_name):

    f = open(file_name)

    single_line = next(f)

    while "Hydrogen bonds:" not in single_line:
        single_line = next(f)

    result = []

    while "pi-pi stacking interactions:" not in single_line:
        result.append(single_line.rstrip())
        single_line = next(f)


    f.close()

    pprint(result)
```

Important to note: after you have opened your file you can still modify it. So the lines you read in your `while` loop might not be the lines you had in mind when you opened `f`.

Output btw:

```
['Hydrogen bonds:',
 '    Location of Donor | Sidechain/Backbone | Secondary Structure | Count',
 '   -------------------|--------------------|---------------------|-------',
 '          LIGAND      |      SIDECHAIN     |        OTHER        |   1',
 '',
 '         RECEPTOR     |      BACKBONE      |         BETA        |   1',
 '',
 'Raw data:',
 '     ATP(1):O2A(9) - A:ILE(61):HN(93) - A:ILE(61):N(92)',
 '',
 'Hydrophobic contacts (C-C):',
 '    Sidechain/Backbone | Secondary Structure | Count',
 '   --------------------|---------------------|-------',
 '         SIDECHAIN     |        OTHER        |   2',
 '         SIDECHAIN     |         BETA        |   23',
 '',
 'Raw data:',
 '     ATP(1):C39(3) - A:TYR(58):CD2(67)',
 '     ATP(1):C39(3) - A:TYR(58):CE2(69)',
 '     ATP(1):C59(6) - A:ILE(61):CD1(100)',
 '     ATP(1):C59(6) - A:LYS(87):CE(344)',
 '     ATP(1):C4(23) - A:PHE(209):CD1(1562)',
 '     ATP(1):C4(23) - A:PHE(209):CE1(1564)',
 '     ATP(1):C2(26) - A:PHE(209):CD2(1563)',
 '     ATP(1):C6(28) - A:PHE(209):CB(1560)',
 '     ATP(1):C6(28) - A:PHE(209):CG(1561)',
 '     ATP(1):C6(28) - A:PHE(209):CD1(1562)',
 '     ATP(1):C6(28) - A:VAL(286):CG2(2266)',
 '']
```